# Setting a time-out limit to readLine()?

Tags: java, sockets, pop3

I have the following code that reads response from a POP server through Sockets in Java. But the problem is sometimes, when I use the readLine() function to read from the server and if the server does not reply with any response, my application will hang there, waiting for a response from the server.

```
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("pop.server.com", 110), 3000);
input = socket.getInputStream();
BufferedReader incoming = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
incoming.readLine();   //This line will cause my application to hang if the server does not respond with a reply
```

Is there a way to set a timeout or some other ways that when the server does not reply after a certain amount of time, the application should stop waiting for a response and continue its other execution?

Comment: Why aren't you using Javamail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you try [Socket.setSoTime(timeout)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29)

Comment: This doesn't timeout on reading the whole line though. What if the client keeps sending bytes but never ends the line??

Comment: @grom That is a risk.  The client can always send you endless data which causes an out of memory error.  If you need custom handling you have to write the code yourself.

Comment: @grom You can use Read() in your own while loop. That method only reads one character. If you combine it with the timeout you should be able to do what you want.
Not quite the same as "write the code yourself" :)